# Import Error: Using Python with Geany

Tags: python, python-2.7, ubuntu, geany

How can I add path to the *PYTHONPATH* environment variable
I tried using "sudo so" in *.bash* and also tried

`export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/home/01_Understand/scitools/bin/linux32/python`

but I am still getting import error. 
I actually want to use **Understand** module (understand.py) with Geany but there is always an error stating

`ImportError: No module named understand`

Can anyone help me in this regard ?

Thanks

Comment: How have you installed the module? either apt or pip/setuptools should take care of adjusting PYTHONPATH for you.

Comment: _The Understand module is located in the SciTools installation directory
at SciTools\bin\<SYSTEM>\python and that path should be added to the
PYTHONPATH environment variable to access these features._

This is what is written on their web page and I am doing accordingly, yet not successful.

Comment: Uff. My first reaction is "if they don't provide an installer it can't be good". Can you, from your user, read the file? Is that directory in your user's PYTHONPATH before starting Python?

Comment: There is just one understand.so file present

Comment: It could be a compiled Python extension. You can inspect the content `nm understand.so`, and see if there is Python stuff (thins like PyNumber_Int).

Comment: just did it and unfortunately there is nothing like python stuff :(

Comment: This is nothing related to Geany. But keep in mind, .bashrc is not parsed on an X environment... this needs to be put into .profile.